# using curl not getting any header information in response string

Tags: php, curl

I'm new to php and curl.  I'm calling a webservice that returns values in headers and a `json` object.

The return string is ONLY has the `json` object, no information about it, so it looks like

```
[{
    "time":"2017-07-18T17:02:57.759Z",
    "trade_id":18237183,
    "price":"2302.53000000",
    "size":"0.03310247",
    "side":"sell"
}]
```

From my understanding the string should have the return headers and other information. (or do I not understand this)

code:

create curl resource

```
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-USD/trades");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//enable headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

// set user agent
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// ONLY DISPLAYS JSON OBJECT NO INFORMTION ON TOP OF STRING
echo( $output);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I copied pasted your code on my side and it does return the headers in the `$output` variable.

Comment: Are you using the same url, Ahhhh still not working for me.

Comment: Yes I copied pasted as it is. Changed nothing. Maybe it's system related? What os are you using? And which version of curl? `var_dump(curl_version());`